# Python parallel append to proxy list return 'function' object is not iterable or 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I want to append list Python parallel processing. I write code as follow:

```
from joblib import Parallel
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
inputs = enumerate(my_list)
lproxy = manager.list()
d = lproxy
d.append([]) #init empty list

num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
_ = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(d[0].append(word) for idx, word in inputs)
```

Then my parallel job return 'NoneType' object is not iterable. How to append to list in above case?
In second example I test Parallel as follow:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def process(word) :
    print(word)
results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(process(word)) for idx, word in inputs)
```

and this return 'function' object is not iterable. Is this function have to be written somehow specially?

What's a god practice of parallel appending to the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a solution:

```
import multiprocessing
inputs = enumerate(my_list)
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
lproxy = manager.list()
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
def process(word) :
    lproxy.append(word)
results = Parallel(n_jobs=num_cores)(delayed(process)(word) for idx, word in inputs)
```

than to extract proxy list I use:

```
l = lproxy[:]
```